# Solve $\frac{b}{a}=a{.}b$ in decimal

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

> Are there any equations of the form $\dfrac{b}{a}=a{.}b$ other than $\dfrac{5}{2}=2.5$?

Denote $n=\lfloor\log_{10}b\rfloor+1,$ then
$$\frac{b}{a}=a{.}b=a+\frac{b}{10^n},\\
b=a^2+\frac{ab}{10^n},a^2<b<a^2+a<(a+1)^2, a=\lfloor\sqrt{b}\rfloor,10^n\mid ab.$$

I searched $b<10^5$ such that $10^n\mid ab$ and got a table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
 b & a & d(b)=a^2+a b/10^n-b \\\hline
 5 & 2 & 0 \\
 75 & 8 & -5 \\
 100 & 10 & 1 \\
 400 & 20 & 8 \\
 500 & 22 & -5 \\
 640 & 25 & 1 \\
 900 & 30 & 27 \\
 2600 & 50 & -87 \\
 5000 & 70 & -65 \\
 6500 & 80 & -48 \\
 9375 & 96 & -69 \\
 10000 & 100 & 10 \\
 25625 & 160 & 16 \\
 31250 & 176 & -219 \\
 40000 & 200 & 80 \\
 62800 & 250 & -143 \\
 65625 & 256 & 79 \\
 76000 & 275 & -166 \\
 90000 & 300 & 270 \\\hline
\end{array}$$

$\frac{b}{a}=a{.}b$ iff $(b)=0$. For example, $d(640)=1\neq0$ and $\frac{640}{25}=25.6$.

Also we can search the solutions start with $a,$ then $n=\lfloor\log_{10}a \rfloor+1$ or $n=\lfloor\log_{10}a\rfloor+2$, $b=\frac{10^n a}{10^a-n}.$

I think someone has conducted research and gives a complete solution to this problem, because the problem is so interesting and natural, so I hope you can give me a reference or write an answer here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to inform, this question for $gcd(a,b)=1$ was in the [Iran NMO second round exam](http://www.alt1.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3047692&sid=cec286d98eb54852263931ea86cdd0e2), question 1 :)

Comment: From $10^na^2+ba-10^nb=0$, it's not hard to show that $b$ must be of the form $2^r5^sk^2$ with $(k,10)=1$. This rules out numbers like $b=2600$ and $b=6500$.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you require a fraction in shortest terms, i.e. $\gcd(a,b)=1$. 
To continue from $$ \frac ba= a+\frac b{10^n}\implies 10^nb=10^na^2+ab$$
we see that not only $$ 10^n\mid 10^n(b-a^2)=ab$$
but also
$$ a\mid a\cdot(10^na+b)=10^n b$$
and $$ b\mid b\cdot(10^n-a)=10^n a^2.$$
With $\gcd(a,b)=1$ this implies $a\mid 10^n$ and $b\mid 10^n$ and (with negatives excluded) ultimately $(a,b)=(2^n,5^n)$ or $(a,b)=(5^n,2^n)$ or $(a,b)=(10^n,1)$ or $(a,b)=(1,10^n)$. The last case is excluded because $b<10^n$ is required, the penultimate case is excluded because it leads to $\frac ba<1<a+\frac b{10^n}$.
So we want to solve 
$$ 10^n 5^n=10^n2^{2n}+2^n5^n\qquad\text{or}\qquad 10^n 2^n=10^n5^{2n}+5^n2^n,$$
or equivalently
$$ 5^n=4^{n}+1\qquad\text{or}\qquad 2^n=25^{n}+1.$$
The only solution is indeed $n=1$ for the left variant (and no solution on the right).

Comment: I really want to know if there are solutions when gcd$(a,b)>1$.

Answer (score 0):

let $10^{k-1} \leq b < 10^k$. Then, $\frac{b}{a} = \overline{a.b} = a + \frac{b}{10^k}$. This leads to the equation $10^k a^2 + ab = 10^k b$. Simplifying, we get $10^k a^2 = (10^k - a) b$.

Since $b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, this implies that $10^k - a | 10^k a^2$, which further implies that $10^k - a | 10^{3k}$. Therefore, $10^k - a = 2^s \cdot 5^t$, where $s, t \in \mathbb{N}$ and $s, t \leq 3k$.

Also, we have $b = \frac{10^k a^2}{10^k - a}$ and $10^{k-1} \leq b < 10^k$. This implies that $a^2 + a < 10^k$.

We only need to prove that when $s = 0$ or $t = 0$ and $a \neq 2$, if $10^k - 2^s \cdot 5^t > 0$, then $10^k - 2^s \cdot 5^t > \sqrt{2^s \cdot 5^t}$. (Otherwise, we subtract the same amount from $s$ and $t$ and get a stronger inequality.) In other words, we need to prove that $2^s + \sqrt{2^s} < 10^{\lceil s \log_{10}(2) \rceil}$, $5^t + \sqrt{5^t} < 10^{\lceil t \log_{10}(5) \rceil}$, $\forall s, t \in \mathbb{Z}^+>3$.

Or $\log_{10}(1+2^{-\frac{x}{2}}) < \{x\log_{10}(5)\}$

$\log_{10}(1+5^{-\frac{x}{2}}) < \{x\log_{10}(2)\}$ , $\quad \forall \, x \in \mathbb{Z}, x > 3$  (I have proven the second inequality already, still working on the first one which is harder.)

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{b}{a} = a.b \implies a^2 + \frac{ab}{10} = b$

$10a^2 + ab = 10b$

For $a = 2$, $40 +2b = 10b \implies b = 5$

The second equation:  ?